# Count number of populated cells in range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I count the number of populated cells (with text/number or combinations of text+number)?

I tried `=countif(A2:A2000,1=1)` (with a general criteria, e.g. 1=1 always) but shows zero (0) for a text column.

Comment: The formula is `=COUNTA(A2:A2000) `: non-blank cells are counted

Comment: @juriruut you should post that as the answer so you might get some imaginary internet points!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula is `=COUNTA(A2:A2000)` : non-blank cells are counted.

Answer (score 11):

I think for the answer above, it should rather be

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:A2000"))
```

I have always faced problems while not mentioning Range, cause it considers the whole range to be as a single unit.

Answer (score 5):

In VBA it's WorksheetFunction.CountA("A2:A2000")

Answer (score 0):

Dim Coloumncount As Integer
 Coloumncount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA([D1:D100])'count how many filled cell in coloumn "D"