# Excel VBA - WorksheetFunction.CountA error - Object required

Tags: excel, vba, object, required

folks.  I'm a programming newbie, trying to write a macro to extract some rows of data from multiple workbooks and compile them into a new workbook, then graph them.  I have figured out how to loop through the source spreadsheets, and a few other things, but right now I'm stuck on a couple of places.  (I'll ask my different questions in different threads for clarity.)

This question is about an error when using WorksheetFunction.CountA to get the number of a list of items I'm searching for.  I want to know the number so that I can know when I have found all of my search strings.  If I can't find them all, I want to inform the user and quit.

Following advice on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245507/excel-vba-count-number-of-populated-cells-in-range), I wrote a snippet to test the CountA function.  I get an "object required" error.   I have reviewed several threads on that topic, but I'm still not getting it.  Here is my code snippet:

```
Sub a_test_kpi_count()

Dim kpi_list_count As Integer

 Set kpi_list_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA("kpi_list")

 MsgBox "There are " & kpi_list_count & "kpis in the list."


End Sub
```

When I run the code, the editor stops with either "kpi_list_count" OR "CountA" highlighted.  Well, THAT'S helpful!

I should add that "kpi_list" is a named range on the worksheet where the macro lives.  However, I get the same error when I specify the range in this manner:

```
Set kpi_list_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA("K3:K7")
```

Ergo, I don't think the named range is my problem.

A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated!

OR, feel free to call me an idiot and point out my obvious error!  ;-)

EDIT:

Thanks, Ben.

This code is working:

```
Sub a_test_KPI_count()

Dim KPIListCount As Long

 KPIListCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("KPI_list"))

 MsgBox "There are " & KPIListCount & "KPIs in the list."

End Sub
```

Thank you!   Oddly, it does NOT work when I use the sheet name, buttons. Are sheet names case sensitive?  I ask because the editor insists on "Buttons" rather than, "buttons".

A couple more questions for my learning, if I may, about some of your tips:

3, long vs. integer.  In this case, I'm counting a short list (<6) items.  Is integer acceptable here, or would it be best practice to stick with Long?

6. Camelcase vs snakecase.  Noted.  Is this simply a preference of more experienced programmers?  Or is there a functional difference?

Your answers have all been of the kind I hope for.  A fishing lesson, rather than a fish!   Thank you!

Comment: Since `kpi_list_count` is an integer, remove `Set`.

Comment: Sheet names are not the same as sheet code names. To use the sheet name, you'd use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Buttons")` instead of `Sheet1`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) for why `Long` is preferable to `Integer`.

Comment: There's no "functional difference" in naming conventions, other than how (positively/negatively) it affects readability and maintainability. There are exactly 0 members in VBA standard libraries that use `snake_case`, that should be a good clue! Also if/when you start doing OOP and implement interfaces, you'll find that underscores in public member names will actually make your code uncompilable, because the underscore *does* have a special meaning in VBA.

Answer (score 4):

1. `Set` is for `Object` variables - remove it.
2. You need a `Range` call when specifying a named range.

   ```
   kpi_list_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("kpi_list"))
   ```
3. 99.9999% of the time you want a `Long`, not an `Integer`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long):

   ```
   Dim kpi_list_count as Long
   ```
4. Best practice is to specify which sheet the `Range` is on (change as necessary):

   ```
   kpi_list_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("kpi_list"))
   ```
5. You can drop the `Application` if you want.
6. Consider using [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) instead of [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Comment: Thank you very much for an educational ansser.   However, I'm still gettgng an "object required" error with both of these approaches.  ' 'KPIListCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("KPI_list"))
 
 KPIListCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Buttons.Range("KPI_list"))'

Comment: Can you edit your question with the revised code you're using?

Comment: Should I do that in the original question?  Still learning the protocol here.

Comment: Yes that would be best. You can add it onto the end, as an "EDIT".

Comment: Note - you can refer to the sheet by sheet name or by sheet code name. I'm using the latter. The code name can be found in the VBEditor. Most likely `Buttons` is not the actual code name of the sheet.